# How to enable TRxDBGrid cell to be editable in delphi7

Tags: delphi

Can anyone kindly tell me how to enable TRxDBGrid cell to be editable in delphi7?
I've set some properties of the TRxDBGrid object as following.
Options:dgEditing => TRUE
ReadOnly => FALSE

And also the columns(cells?) as following

### ReadOnly => FALSE

But it doesn't help.

Theres's little infos for delphi 7 since It's too old.And the issue costs me too much time.
Thanks for helping. 
Best regards.

Comment: Perhaps the underlying dataset is read-only?

Comment: make a small example, and post the code here. have you verified the state of the dataset behind the grid(is in edit mode, browse,etc)?

Comment: You're so kind. I will check the DS right now.

Comment: What i want exact is when i click on the cell,the cursor will enter the cell for editing.And I can write some code to update the tables in the DB after posting.But now I can not enter the cell.Any suggestion?Or anyone can tell me the standard methods for my purpose in delphi?

Comment: What is the dataset that the grid's datasource is connected to? If it's a query with a join (more than one table), you may have issues with editing in the grid. Also, check the datasource, and make sure that it's AutoEdit property is True; if it's not, you have to explicitly call the dataset's Edit or Insert method.

Comment: Thanks for replay.It sounds great and bright.I will check now.

Comment: Dear Ken.YOU'RE right.The query txt is a SQL with table join , the AutoEdit is open. Any method can enable i entering the cell for editing?

Comment: That depends entirely on the database you're querying from, but most databases don't allow an edit on joined table results, as there's no way for it to automatically be able to figure out how to update what you're changing. What I usually do is use a TClientDataSet instead of the query results directly, and have it handle the ApplyUpdates; you can use the BeforeApplyUpdates and AfterApplyUpdates to handle anything it can't automatically, and OnReconcileError to handle problems. You then attach the ClientDataset to the grid instead of your query directly.

Answer (score 0):

That does not sound like a problem with TRxDBGrid. I have used it for long time now and there was never such a problem. I am quite sure that your underlying Datasource is ReadOnly or the Dataset is "ReadOnly" in some kind. Maybe you can test is with a second TDBGrid on the Form?